# Image invisible in iPad because wrong Xcode folder management

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I have small problem. When I launch my app in emulator it works just fine, but when I launch it on my iPad I cant see the images of the buttons. The background is OK. Image 1.jpg is shown, but images in General folder like contour buttons is invisible on iPad. Other images like Glasses.png that in other screen are shown fine also. The image 1.jpg is defined via code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[mainImgae setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"Iview images/Bike/100/comp/1.jpg"]];
}
```

And other images for buttons selected via storyboard. I think my folder management is wrong, but i have to manage it in folders, so they will be in folders at my project folder.

[image]

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, but what software did you use to annotate the screenshot?

Comment: Snagit, it very useful and easy to edit screenshots and add arrows and comments.

Comment: try to rotate the device.,.i think it is because of autosizing,.in the simulator it will be in landscpe mode. change the device in to potrait mode or landscape mode.. i am just guessing.,.

Comment: The device is in landscape mode.

Comment: have u rotated the simulator.,

Comment: Yes, it have nothing to do with rotation.

Comment: found answer for ur question??

Comment: No, that`s the reason i asked it here!

Comment: try to clean the Project and run it,.to clean the Project Press shift+windows+k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[mainImgae setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"1.jpg"]];
```

this is enough for putting image for mainimage.,.

Comment: I know, but i have many images that named 1.jpg that is the reason i use folders. The answer is have nothing to do with the question. I mentioned that 1.jpg is shown fine.

Comment: There is NO problem with the main image! And you can see that the images authorized.